# How to load CSS, JS, images in JSP in Spring Maven project?

Tags: spring, maven, jsp

```
 `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
            <html>
            <head>
             <link href='<c:url value="/resources/css/epds1.css" />' rel='stylesheet'>
            
            
            <title>FOOD SECURITY CARDS</title>
            </head>`[![This is My Jsp Page][ In this Page i need load js ,css,images]][i tried doing from all sources but no use]
       ----------
    **Spring Application config file**
    
     `<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
            xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd    
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
        
            <context:annotation-config />
            <context:component-scan base-package="com.nic.controller"></context:component-scan>
            <bean id="viewResolver"
                      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
                      <property name="prefix">
                          <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
                       </property>
                      <property name="suffix">
                         <value>.jsp</value>
                      </property>
                </bean>
        
        
            <mvc:annotation-driven />
            <mvc:resources location="/resources/**" mapping="/resources/" />`
```

Above is the project structure. I want to know how to load all static resources in Spring JSP page.
I tried doing from all sources and different ways: `<mvc:resources location="/resources/**" mapping="/resources/" /> <link rel='stylesheet' href='<c:url value="/resources/css/epds1.css" />' />` but still didn't worked for me.

Comment: `<link rel='stylesheet' href='<c:url value="/resources/css/epds1.css" />' />` like you have should work without issues. There is probably something else wrong, but you need to include your spring config and pom.xml to find out what.

Comment: also verify you have `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>` in the beginning of your jsp

Comment: Yes I added all the code u mentioned  above but problem still persists

Comment: can you add to the question what you have in the jsp and what is the HTML output?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your .jsp files :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
```

and then you can access the .css files

```
<link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: No it had not worked for me Adrian web and at runtime this is the path rendering in jsp page  <link href="/FoodSecurityAct/FoodSecurityAct/resources/css/epds1.css" rel="stylesheet"> after adding ur code